# Umbrella Exception in #google-apis-explorer

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-apis-explorer

After upgrading the **Google Cloud Endpoints** Java framework to v2, as well as upgrading from Java 7 to Java 8 using the Google API Explorer #google-apis-explorer, The Explorer opens the APIs list but when open the API method to perform a call nothing returns and seems can't found the API method
and throw this Umbrella exception, even though calling the API works fine.

```
Uncaught Error: com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Exception caught: undefined
    at UmbrellaException_0.createError (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:12743)
    at UmbrellaException_0.initializeBackingError (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:12793)
    at UmbrellaException_0.Throwable_2 (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:12689)
    at UmbrellaException_0.Exception_2 (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:12873)
    at UmbrellaException_0.RuntimeException_2 (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:36112)
    at UmbrellaException_0.UmbrellaException (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:56492)
    at new UmbrellaException_0 (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:56547)
    at HandlerManager.fireEvent_1 [as fireEvent] (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:56196)
    at FlexTable.fireEvent (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:3323)
    at fireNativeEvent (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:23173)
    at FlexTable.onBrowserEvent (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:3372)
    at dispatchEventImpl (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:63206)
    at dispatchEvent_3 (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:63196)
    at HTMLTableElement.dispatchEvent_5 (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:64267)
    at apply_57 (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:50314)
    at entry0 (com.google.api.explorer.Explorer-0.js:50378)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous>
```

[I used to get this before migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMo0f.png)
[But after Migration Nothing return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GustM.png)

Comment: Could you please be more specific and explain a little bit better what your issue is? How was your application working before the upgrade?

Comment: Thanks for the update. When you migrated the framework and the Java version, did you follow [these](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating) [steps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8)? Could you please add the piece of code that causes the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you annotating your APIs? I had the same problem after migration and the problem was lower case httpMethod, before migration my API looked like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getSomething", httpMethod = "get")
```

but after migration you have to use upper case httpMethods:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getSomething", httpMethod = "GET")
```

or

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getSomething", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was annotating it "get" once I changed it to HttpMethod.GET it's done (y)